# Asking questions on topics frequented by users I don't want to interact with

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rude-or-abusive

There's a topic I'm interested in on Stack Overflow. I asked a question for which I received some very useful answers.

This is also not my first question. I've been on Stack Overflow for a number of years, asked over 100 questions, mostly well received, and provided over 600 answers, also mostly well received. I always try to be helpful, nice and diplomatic when answering.

Along with the nice people answering my question, there's also a person that could not provide anything other than condescending comments and a bully attitude. I do not experience this often on Stack Overflow. At least not on the previous topics I've been active on.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any escaping this person if I want to have anything to do with this topic. He's everywhere, answering, commenting, and editing almost every question that relates to the topic. Seeing his comments raises my pulse and makes me want to quit posting questions on Stack Overflow altogether. I was very tempted to delete my question, but others have taken the time to provide useful answers which I know will help people in the future.

What can I do about this? I would like to continue participating, as this is the only person with an offensive attitude, and the rest seem rather nice. I can't ban him from participating on my questions.

Do I raise rudeness flags? He has over 200k reputation, not sure how much that would help. Also, by the time I get to raise the rudeness flag, my whole day is already ruined, I'm already very aggravated and regretting the fact that I asked the question.

Is my only option to quit participating in this topic?

Comment: Just because someone has 200k+ reputation doesn't mean they're immune to flags. If you feel that a comment is particularly rude, then flag it as such using the *"It's unfriendly or unkind."* option. If there are a stream of comments on the same question that are, then raise a custom moderator flag on the question/answer, and explain why you're flagging. Even if the comments are deleted afterwards, the flag will still be checked by the moderator team. If the user is particularly rude, they can reach out to them.

Comment: Repuation doesn't play a role when evaluating rude content. But please make sure that when you flag a comment as rude or abusive, that the comment is really rude. I guess the question here is forced by you last question, but it seems there are already several comments missing in that conversation. On first glance, none of the comments there seems particularly rude.

Comment: It could also simply be a language thing. For a vast number of users on SO English is not their 1st (or even 2nd, 3rd) language; I think many of us (especially those of us where it is our 1st, or are very fluent) forget this. People often type how they would speak, and non-native speakers more easily get language "wrong". I know when I type, i type how i speak, but I *am* quite sarcastic but also my tone is very expressive. That is lost when I type and many do find my written language "rude". When they realise that I type as I speak they see it in another light.

Comment: On SO, and for those I don't work with, they don't know me as personally. That *is* a failing on my part for how i type; but honestly, it's unlikelyI'm ever going to change, :)

Comment: I've looked at your latest question and I'm pretty sure I know which user you mean. Yes, looks like they can be pretty "in yo' face". Most of their comments are pretty topical though, even if somewhat nitpicky. The first step is to take a deep breath. The second is to ignore them if you don't want to engage. The third is to flag their comments as rude ***if they really are***. So far the user *hasn't* accumulated many flags at all, despite being very active.

Comment: I see your points, and moderators might think the same. This is not particularly rude, the user has no grounds for the flag. But picture this: I ask a question and receive helpful answers. Then I get a comment: "your question was answered here, here, here and here". Links go to answers that have some similarity, but are not exact. Then he edits your question. You say thanks for the edit, but that's not exactly right, for this reason. He then says "of course it is, you even saids so yourself". You say thank you for the links but they're not responding to this question exactly.

Comment: He says then "have you looked and have you tried?". By this time I'm already extremely annoyed. He's not technically rude. He's condescending.

Comment: If you were to talk to someone like this in real life, you might feel a strong urge to smack him.

Comment: I doesn't take much guessing to find out what user you are having trouble with. If they are rude, just flag away. If they find themselves on the receiving end of rude flags too often, they'll enjoy a timeout to concentrate on other things. At the same time, I would recommend not to take things too personally. Expressions like _"Seeing his comments raises my pulse"_ make it sound as if maybe you should just ignore them and disengage. You are not forced to reply to any user that comments on your posts.

Comment: The urge to smack someone is very understandable, but at the same time we need to learn to live with the people around us. You _wouldn't_ smack them in real life probably, you'd just learn to avoid them. While on here it's hard to avoid someone if you're "sharing the same tag", you are free to *ignore* them. And just as you might report a really problematic colleague to your boss, you can flag really problematic behaviour for moderator attention.

Comment: @deceze and yivi, yes, I think I'm a bit too bothered by this. I wish everyone was as peaceful as they are on the other topics I frequent. I suppose I'm spoiled. I'll do my best to be calm and try again. Thank you for the helpful comments.

Comment: @deceze, exactly. The good thing about real life is that you *can* avoid them. I wish there was a filter for that on StackOverflow as well.

Comment: If you never had a co-worker or boss you positively detested, and had no choice but to make do and work with them in a civilized way... I truly envy you.

Comment: @yivi, ha! One should be so lucky :)

Comment: If you are truly interacting that often with this user, have you considered inviting them to chat to have a casual conversation to see where they are coming from? Comments can often come across as harsh whereas the user is simply using a terse format for the sake of brevity and not offense.

Comment: As an option you can make your alias to be know for completely unreasonable/unpleasant interactions (requires effort, may not suit everyone) or simply rename account to match one of existing once... This should solve most of your issues - old time/frequent users will try to ignore such posts and you get answers/comments from newish users only.